# Obtaining accessToken when google sign-in firebase flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I tried to create google sign-in function for my web-app, but I am stuck when I tried to get the access token, please help me to review my code, why I the result like this? Shouldn't the accessToken start with something like eyJhbGci...
[image]

```
const List<String> scopes = <String>['email', 'profile'];

GoogleSignIn signIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: scopes);

Future<void> handleSignIn() async {
  try {
    GoogleAuthProvider authProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
    User? user;
    String? token;
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(authProvider);
      token = userCredential.credential!.accessToken;
      print(token);
      user = userCredential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if (!user.isNull) {
      setSharedPref(
          name: user!.displayName, token: token, imageUrl: user.photoURL);
      PostResponseModel model = await signInJWT(token ?? '');
      if (model.errors!.errorCode.isNull) {
        print(model.data.toString());
      } else
        print(model.errors!.errorMessage);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```